# Reducing Number of Files and Folders in Information Server

Tags: ibm-information-server

Because of the presence of a huge quantity of files under a folder present in Docstore, the tool is loading indefinetly.

Does anyone know a way to delete/unmount folders/files only from Docstore and not from file system (because of business needs).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your query is no. Choices are

- Periodically purging old doc unnecessary doc store files is a performance best practice. Check this link. You may want to leverage IBM MDMPIM DocStore Maintenance Script  job and IBM_MDMPIM_DocStore_Maintenance_Lookup lkp table. 
   
  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWSR9_11.4.0/com.ibm.pim.adm.doc/sys_admin/pim_con_docstoremaintenance.html
- If inbound parameter is set to yes in $TOP/etc/default/docstore_mount.xml  then periodically moving the file system files to another backup location (using some cronjobs that moves files on a scheduled fashion) would be ideal choice. This will allow you to see the folder in doc store but will get to see files created since last backup.
- If you altogether don't want to see the folder in doc store at all then remove corresponding entry in $TOP/etc/default/docstore_mount.xml  and recycle MDM CE application.